# Having trouble with scroll in 3-level expandable list view Android

Tags: android, expandablelistview, multi-level

I have a 3-level expandable list view. And a Pull to refresh control on top of list view.
Now, when i try to browse list from top to bottom, pull to refresh menu is detected. Instead of appearing on the first cell of the list, it may appear on any cell browsing from top to bottom.

please refer screenshot